# Image.prefetch JSON error in React Native?

Tags: react-native

We want to use the Image.prefetch api and for a simple test are seeing a json parsing error. version of RN is 0.41.1.

`var prefetchTask = Image.prefetch('http://origami.design/public/images/bird-logo.png');`

the error returned is below. Has anyone seen this problem and can help explain what we're doing wrong here on the `.prefetch` call ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hmm i think i've answered my own question on this one, looks like the image endpoint needs to be **https://**